# executing 'perf' within a C program

Tags: c, ubuntu, fork, perf

I need to be able execute 'perf stats' within a C program to gather real time execution statistics of a particular function that is executed inside a loop. A shell script ('perfExecution.sh') is created which includes,

```
pid=$(pgrep programName)
perf stat -e cycles,instructions,cache-misses:uk -p $pid 2>perf_stat.out 1>temp2.out
```

Here the 'programeName' is the name of my C programme and the 'perfExecution.sh' is executed as a child process within the main C program before the functions that should be analyzed are called.

```
pid_t childPID = fork();
char perfBuf[200];
int pid = getpid();
if ( childPID == -1 )
{
   printf( "failed to fork child\n" );
   _exit( 1 );
}
else if ( childPID == 0 )
{
   std::cout << "started stat collection for: " << pid << "\n";

   sprintf(perfBuf, "/home/user/Documents/Project/perfExecution.sh");
   system(perfBuf);
}
/*
  Functions to be measured.
*/
kill( childPID, SIGKILL );
/*
    Collect the statistics generated from perf.
*/
 `
```

The output file always returns blank, even though the it gets the performance statistics when the 'perfExecution.sh' is manually executed in another terminal. Could someone please let me know how to correctly capture the required statistics within the program it self?.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is C?  This looks like C++ to me.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Indeed the `std::cout` ... is C++, but the question is all about C.

Comment: Another solution is to use `fork()` and a variation of `exec()`

Comment: @userDtrm Why don't you use the "-o file" option of "perf stat" to write the output of the command in a file? And why do you absolutely want to run perf from inside your program to analyze its execution? In what running "perf stat -o outputfile.stats programName" is not appropriate?

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I was able to achieve the requirement by using the command "killall -INT perf" instead of the "kill( childPID, SIGKILL );" command. This ensured that the functions to be measured are correctly recored at the output file.

Comment: @userDtrm You say in your initial description that you want to get statistics on a particular function but that appears nowhere in the code or elsewhere and my fear is you made something complex (fork(), several calls to system(), ...) that introduced a bias in results you will collect.

Comment: @amigadev Yes I'm working on verifying the solution. The command you suggested (i.e., "perf stat -o outputfile.stats programName") will not work in this case as the functions I need to check reside within the program and the complexity of these will differ in each iteration. For example a frame decoding instance. So here I create child process to initiate 'perf' and then the actual functions that are executed in the main process will be measured by perf.

Comment: @userDtrm Ok, thanks for explanation, I understand better what you do ... even if I still have doubts about accuracy of results you could get (that also depends on the time of the function(s) you measure). Another question: Why do you collect with "perf stat" and not "perf record" with selected event(s)? Thus you could report the number of samples associated with the function(s) you want to track.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to achieve what you're trying to do would be to use the perf_events API (or another such API, like PAPI). This would allow you from within your code to profile the section you're interested in.

The solution you're trying to use (calling the perf binary within your code) is an ugly hack.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `perf_event_open()`

They also have sample code at the end.

http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html

Comment: Thanks for this input. This seem to suite my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* put script code here or in a header file of your choice */
#define SCRIPT "\
for ((j=0 ; j < 5 ; j++))\n\
do\n\
echo \"Count: $i\"\n\
done\n\
"

int main(void)
{
  system(SCRIPT);
  return 0;
}
```

Can read more here: http://www.unix.com/programming/216190-putting-bash-script-c-program.html

To Capture the output type `man popen` on command line and read about popen

Comment: Thanks. Yes, general scripts do work in this fashion. I found it doesn't work that way for the 'perf stat' script which I have mentioned in the question. Do you have any idea as to why?.

Comment: @Kaleb I am sorry but I don't understand in what the code above helps solving the initial problem.